# Failure to login using Facebook Sdk: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-facebook

Inside MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    String[] fragmentTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bottom_nav);
        mBottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnChildClickedListener(new OnChildClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildClicked(int child) {
                selectFragment(child);
            }
        });
        //setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectFragment(0);
            //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        }
    }

    private void selectFragment(int child) {
        switch (child){
            case 0:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content, HomeFragment.newInstance(fragmentTitles[child], child))
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content, SearchFragment.newInstance(fragmentTitles[child], child))
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                        .replace(R.id.content, ProfileFragment.newInstance(fragmentTitles[child], child))
                        .commit();

        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside Fragment.java

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mContext);
        loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
        //textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {   
                final String token =  loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken().toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                //textView.setText("Login Canceled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });    
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.startActivityForResult(data, resultCode);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: picker.novasyslabs.com.picker, PID: 23337
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {picker.novasyslabs.com.picker/picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3391)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3434)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.Activities.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:78)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3434) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23337 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I have posted the logcat.
I want to log in with facebook inside ProfileFragment but when I'm trying to login inside Fragment then it asks for login and password and login is success from facebook then i can back to fragment at the moment Application Terminates and I'm not getting what to do to solve this problem.
Please help to solve this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your `ProfileFragment`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Also if you call `setRetainInstance(true)` in your `fragmentManager` remove it.

Comment: try removing the `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in your mainactivity...also post the full code..of your activty

Comment: have u got any solution. please anyone help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in `oncreateView`

You need to call `setFragment` method on `loginButton` in `oncreateview` method.

```
loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_bn);
loginButton.setFragment(this);
```